# Turn off the setting of QGIS to produce XML when closing Raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, xml

Every time I open and close a Raster layer in QGIS it creates an `XML`-file for that raster when closing.

While I do a lot of automatic processing this really bugs me, since I have to add every time when I request a file list to exclude `XML`-files. I just want QGIS to stop doing this, so do any of you know where to turn this off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are the xml files *.aux.xml?

If so,  it's not QGIS creating them,  it's the GDAL library which uses them to store metadata,  including statistics. You can disable completely by setting the environment variable GDAL_PAM_ENABLED=NO though I don't advise this if you'll be displaying the rasters again as there won't be any statistics cached.

Comment: Hi Luke, it does indeed create an aux.xml file. Could you tell me how to change these settings of GDAL? I'm working on Ubuntu and I tried adding it to the .bashrc file, but with no effect.

Comment: Found it in QGIS-Settings-Environment Settings

Comment: @jonasvanduijvenbode setting the environment variable in the settings had no effect for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: If QGIS is creating `*.aux.xml` files, changing `GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR` will have **no effect**. According to the [GDAL docs](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html#persistent-auxiliary-metadata-pam-options), the variable only works if you don't have write permissions to the original directory.

Comment: @AaronZuspan according to the doc that is correct now. However, eight years ago this very old answer worked (and was marked correct). Feel free to add a more up to date answer or edit this one.

Answer (score 4):

To disable the creation of `.aux.xml` files after deleting the raster layer - place the `startup.py` file in the `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3` folder with this code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_PAM_ENABLED", "NO")
```

Comment: you can also add this file to `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default` (for linux) and with `from osgeo import gdal` instead of `import gdal` as the first line.

Comment: I think it's better to add this as an environment variable. It be done using QGIS graphical interface in your settings. Just another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `*.aux.xml` files are called persistent auxiliary metadata (PAM), and are created by GDAL to cache image statistics and speed up subsequent reads. If you want to disable their creation through QGIS, you can go into Settings > Options > System > Environment and add a new variable `GDAL_PAM_ENABLED=NO`. QGIS will need to be restarted for the change to take effect.

[image: QGIS options dialog]

Note that setting `GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR` will *not* affect creation of *.aux.xml files in most cases, as explained in the [GDAL docs](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html#persistent-auxiliary-metadata-pam-options):

> GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR=value: Directory to which .aux.xml files will be written when accessing files from a location where the user does not have write permissions. **Has no effect when accessing files from locations where the user does have write permissions.**

Comment: This is a good answer.